# MVC4 HTML.ValidationMessageFor is not showing validation messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, c#-4.0, razor

I am trying to figure out ,why my validation messages are not showing up?

Here is my Razor page

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    var listErrors = ViewBag.listErrors as Array;
}
<section class="selectconfiguration">
    <h3 class="active">Add Rule</h3>
    <div class="con-section">

         @{Html.EnableClientValidation(true);}
        @{Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();}
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddRules", "Aliases", "HttpPost"))
        {


            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="phone-options-label-column">
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.Label("Alias String:")
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.AliasString,new {@id="txtAliasString"})
                    </td>
                    <td> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AliasString)</td>

                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td class="options-label-column">
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.Label("Select an Associated Model:")
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       @Html.DropDownList("ddlModels", new SelectList(Model.Models, "Id", "Name", ""), "Unknown", new { @class = "mselectDDContItem" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        }
       <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Add Rule" id="btnAddRule" name="AddRule" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
  public class MyViewModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "alias string required")]
            [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "AliasString cannot be larger than 30 characters")]
           public string AliasString { get; set; }      
           public IEnumerable<IParameter> Models { get; set; }
           public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
        }
```

On clciking the addRules button triggers my jquery clcik event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnAddRule").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var params = {
                'aliasString': $("#txtAliasString").val(),
                'modelId': $("#ddlModels").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Aliases/AddRules",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                traditional: true,
                contentType: 'application/json',
            }).done(function () {
            }).complete(function () {
            }).success(function (dv) {
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

and I have these script references also on my layout page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.treeview.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/global.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.nad.session.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")"></script>
```

I dont understhnad why the validations are not firing.
If I click the button with the empty textbox also ,I can see post back happens and modelstate.isValid is returning true to the controller.

Comment: *I can see post back happens and modelstate.isValid is returning true to the controller.* Under what circumstances?

Comment: Have you included the necessary javascript libraries?

Comment: Try [Required(**AllowEmptyStrings = false**, ErrorMessage = "...")]

Comment: @WeTTTT That will make no difference, given that it defaults to false anyway.

Comment: Try dropping the `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js` script.

Comment: Also check that `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` are true in your web.config appSettings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my jquery  button click function ,I added ,$('#myForm').valid() and then my validation started showing up.

```
$("#btnAddRule").click(function (e) {


if ($('#myForm').valid()) {



}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put submit button inside the form and validation would work